# How do I calculate Euclidean distances across NA values in r

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a date frame like this

```
individual <- c("1",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"1","1")
x <- c(665,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,663,665)
y <- c(-474.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-474.5,-472.5)
frame <- rep(1:10)
df <- data.frame(individual,x,y,frame)
```

I have an ID column labeled 'individual', xy coordinates, and a frame number.

I need to calculate the euclidean distances for the x,y coordinates between rows but over the NA values.

So, in the example I gave - I would need to calculate the distances between rows 1 and 9, as well as 10 and 9. In the real data there would be substantially more rows of course.

Eventually what I need to do is interpolate the data, so that if the euclidean distance is <5, fill in the data rows that are missing with the ID of the individual. If the euclidean distance is >5, then ignore and interpolate nothing.

Here is the example result data frame that's needed:

```
individual <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1")
x <- c(665,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,663,665)
y <- c(-474.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-474.5,-472.5)
frame <- rep(1:10)
dist_measure <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2.828427)
df <- data.frame(individual,x,y,frame,dist_measure)
```

Any advice on an approach to this problem is greatly appreciated. My first thought was to have a function that calculates Euclidean distance and put it in a for loop. But I'm a bit stuck on how to work this over the NA values. I thought somehow using the lag function in the tidyverse would help, but not sure again how to integrate that into the loop/function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a bad idea to name a data.frame `data.frame`. Use `df` or `my_data_frame` instead.

Comment: Fair point, fixed - thanks

Comment: With many more individuals, how are you able to identify the `NA` values that might belong to each one?  For example, does `frame` vary consistently within individuals? Will there always be a first and last observed value and everything in between could potentially be attributed to the same individual?

Comment: Good point, should have been clearer. There can be multiple individuals within a given frame. So frame 1 could have multiple individuals, thus 2 rows for frame 1, etc. There might sometimes only be 1 observed value per individual, thus only a first observed value and no last observed value. Those would also be ignored since there would be nothing to interpolate in-between (which is fine).

Comment: @cebola OK, so I think the question still stands, how do you identify a "chunk" of data that might be interpolated based on the distance? Would it be everything between the first and last observed value for that individual?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If there's a first and last observed value for the individual, it would be everything in-between.

Comment: Please make an example with more than one individual per frame, some missing values and your expected output based on this data. As DaveArmstrong pointed out: This makes everything way more complex.

Comment: I see that. I'll be more accurate in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  I've added another individual into the hypothetical data to show how it works.

```
individual <- c("1",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"1","1", 
                "2",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2","2")
x <- c(665,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,663,665, 
       .665,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,.663,.665)
y <- c(-474.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-474.5,-472.5, 
       -.4745,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-.4745,-.4725)
frame <- rep(1:10, 2)
df <- data.frame(individual,x,y,frame)


for(i in 1:2){
  tmp <- df[min(which(df$individual == as.character(i))):
              max(which(df$individual == as.character(i))), ]
  ends <- range(which(is.na(tmp$individual))) + c(-1,1)
  if(nrow(tmp) > 1 & ends[1] > 0 & ends[2] <= nrow(tmp)){
   d <- c(dist(tmp[ends, c("x", "y")]))
   if(d < 5){
     df$individual[min(which(df$individual == as.character(i))):
                     max(which(df$individual == as.character(i)))] <- tmp$individual[ends[1]]
   }
  }
}

df
#    individual       x         y frame
# 1           1 665.000 -474.5000     1
# 2           1      NA        NA     2
# 3           1      NA        NA     3
# 4           1      NA        NA     4
# 5           1      NA        NA     5
# 6           1      NA        NA     6
# 7           1      NA        NA     7
# 8           1      NA        NA     8
# 9           1 663.000 -474.5000     9
# 10          1 665.000 -472.5000    10
# 11          2   0.665   -0.4745     1
# 12          2      NA        NA     2
# 13          2      NA        NA     3
# 14          2      NA        NA     4
# 15          2      NA        NA     5
# 16          2      NA        NA     6
# 17          2      NA        NA     7
# 18          2      NA        NA     8
# 19          2   0.663   -0.4745     9
# 20          2   0.665   -0.4725    10
```

Comment: Thank you @DaveArmstrong. It works perfectly for individual 2 but is there a reason it doesn't for individual 1? The distance should also be the same for that individual.

Comment: It's not, note that the values of `x` and `y` are divided by 1000 for individual 2.  The distance for individual 1 is 1971.363 and for individual 2 is 1.971363., so it does the right thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that the distance between row #9 and row #1 (for individual 1) should also be less than 5 as it is in row #19 and row #11, so I would expect also the rows to be interpolated for both individuals in this example (from your line if(d < 5))

Comment: Individual 1 has three pairs of values 1-9, 1-10 and 9-10.  Is it all of the pairwise distances then that have to be less than 5?

Comment: Nope just between the gaps in the frame numbers/rows, so 1 and 9 here.

Comment: OK @cebola, I understand now.  I edited the answer to reflect my new understanding.